# Access database and C# issues with auto increment primary key

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a form with first name , last name , email, supervisor. I then have my code behind on button set to this

```
  private void agentInsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into Agents values ([FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Supervisor])", con);


            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agentNametextBox1.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agentLastNametextBox4.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agentEmailtextBox3.Text.ToString();
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Supervisor", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = agentSupervisortextBox2.Text.ToString();

            con.Open();
            ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        };
```

I am getting error number of query values and destination fields are not the same . I am sure it is how I have the DB sending over the variables and the AgentID causing the issue. I am new to access but that is what my work is wanting to use. Look forward to a solid answer.

I am just using a simple access database named Agents

Fields are

```
AgentID - auto number
FirstName - text
LastName - text 
Email - text
Supervisor - text
```

Comment: you either need to use your parameters as you declared them (`@firstname`) or use question mark placeholders (`?`)

Comment: Also, is there something about the error that indicated to you that it is a pk problem? sounds like a parameters problem

Comment: Why on earth are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` on the `InsertCommand` of a data adapter?  If you have a data adapter then you are supposed to be populating a `DataTable` with the changes and calling `Update` on the data adapter.  If you're not going to call `Update` then the adapter is pointless so get rid of it.  Just create the command and call `ExecuteNonQuery` on it.

Comment: You can also remove the `.ToString()` calls on the `.Text` property of the TextBoxes (since the property is already a string and you aren't passing a formatProvider). Probably gets compiled away, but the code would be cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write an `INSERT` statement it must either be like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (ValueList)
```

in which case you must provide values for every column and in the order that they were added to the table, or like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnList) VALUES (ValueList)
```

in which case you can specify a subset of the columns and in any order.  You have done neither.  You have done this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (ColumnList)
```

which is meaningless.  Your SQL needs to be like this:

```
insert into Agents ([FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[Supervisor]) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Supervisor)
```

Note that the values now match the parameters that you add to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this

```
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into Agents values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Supervisor)", con);
```

or

```
    ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into Agents (FirstName,LastName,Email,Supervisor) values (@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Supervisor)", con);
```

Comment: That first one won't work because you have to provide a value for every column if you omit the column list.

Answer (score 0):

OleDb is index-based and doesn't use named parameters.

Change as follows:

```
ad.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into Agents (FirstName, LastName, Email, Supervisor) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", con);

ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", agentNametextBox1.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", agentLastNametextBox4.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", agentEmailtextBox3.Text);
ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", agentSupervisortextBox2.Text);
```

Comment: It is indexed-based but it still allows you to use parameter names.  It will ignore them but it is still a good idea to use them because them because it makes your code clearer.